# Why do I get a down vote when asking for clarification about notations and explanations about proofs?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, down-votes, unanswered-questions

Recently in some of my [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809688/notation-questions-about-ar-1-to-ar-an-to-m1-0-ldots-0-to-x-1-ldots), also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800585/what-does-it-mean-by-extending-a-commutative-diagram-in-snake-lemma), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687308/meaning-of-textbfsmall-in-category-theory), I have been getting down votes.  The latter two, others have voted back up to make it zero. I am just wondering if people on MSE don't like questions about asking for clarifications about math concepts written from text?  I also noticed sometimes in posts that have downvoted being cast, they don't get answered.  I thought a question get downvoted if the person asking have not shown any research effort, whatever "research effort" suppose to mean.  What is the equivalent of showing research effort in the context of asking for clarification when it comes to not understanding what one is reading and asking help for clarification.

Thank you in advance.

I understand that

Comment: I see only one downvote on the three questions. The reason for the sole downvote you got is unclear and I suggest you ignore it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan would getting downvotes to questions has an advevrse affect on whether others would be willing to answer your post?  The reasons I don't get downvotes on the other two votes,because others up voted to get it back to zero.  Still, I am just wondering if there are reasons that I should be concerned about in how I approach to asking questions, especially when I need clarifications or explanations about things I don't understand from math texts.

Comment: Look more closely and you will find only one downvote in your 3 links, just as I said.

Comment: @MoisheKohan kk, thank you.

Comment: The 2nd & 3rd links go to the same question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you for letting me know. it should point to the correct post.

Comment: What is the meaning of the last fragment in this post?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you were downvoted, and I doubt anyone can answer that -- you received only one downvote, and only the person who cast that single downvote knows why they did so.

But I can offer some feedback on your questions.  In the future, please ask only one question per post.  This is a question-and-answer site, and the intention that there is one question per post.  Also, we are most interested in questions that will be useful to others in the future, if that helps you in framing your questions.